# Angular Material Expansion Panel default close except the one with routerLinkActive

Tags: angular, angular-material

I'm using Expansion Panel for my side nav with navigation links. I want them all to be closed except the one with active router link but can't figure out how to.

```
  <mat-expansion-panel [routerLinkActive]="['is-active']" [expanded]="true">
    <mat-expansion-panel-header>
      <mat-panel-title>
        Nav Item
      </mat-panel-title>
    </mat-expansion-panel-header>

    <mat-list-item *ngFor="let navLink of navLinks" routerLink="{{ navLink.routerLink }}"
      [routerLinkActive]="['is-active']">

      <a>{{ navLink.text }}</a>
    </mat-list-item>
  </mat-expansion-panel>
```

I tried to bind `expanded` with `routerLinkActive` but not getting expected result. All headers are closed, even the active route one. However the active route header show like it's in expanded status but the child items won't show up

```
<mat-expansion-panel [routerLinkActive]="['is-active']" [expanded]="rla.isActive" #rla="routerLinkActive">
```

Someone know the issue or if you have a more correct way to do it ?

Answer (score 1):

I know this is an old post, but maybe this will be helpful to anyone.

To have the mat-expansion-panel opened when the router link is active is to disable the mat-expansion-panel animation.

To disable just add `[@.disabled]="true"`

For example:

```
...
<mat-expansion-panel
  #rla="routerLinkActive"
  [@.disabled]="true" 
  [routerLinkActiveOptions]="{ exact: true }"
  [class.mat-elevation-z0]="true"
  [expanded]="rla.isActive"
  routerLinkActive="active">
...
</mat-expansion-panel>
...
```

Answer (score 0):

`routerLinkActive` will only add / remove css classes. [Source](https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/2a61728137c8107c5b8f194c89ff9318b4d11034/packages/router/src/directives/router_link_active.ts#L152)

What can work is to listen to **Router events** something like this:

```
  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.router.events.subscribe(evt => {
      if (evt instanceof NavigationEnd) {
        this.currentRoute = evt.url; <-- update local var to hold "current" route url
      }
    });
  }
```

In your html you can bind to `expanded`

```
 <mat-expansion-panel [expanded]="currentRoute === '/alpha'">
```

[Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-pwqthw?file=src%2Fapp%2Fexpansion-expand-collapse-all-example.html)

Comment: I understand that part of `routerLinkActive`. My point is I was trying to use the `isActive` flag, see my second block of code. I've confirmed the flag changes value correctly when I changed route, but it doesn't work when trying to bind with `expanded`. But anyway, I think your solution works without lot of code added.